# JQuery .text() is removing my input tags checkbox completely

Tags: jquery, html

I don't think I can explain this too good in words, so I made a fiddle for you guys:

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m4bgyq8/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $("#label1").text("test1234");
    $("#label2").text("test1234");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>
    <label id="label1">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
       Label 1
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
    <label id = "label2" for="checkbox_id">
      Label 2
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="clickMe">
Click me
</button>
```

As you can see, I prepared one input checkbox surrounded by a label, and one where the label is assigned via the `for="..."` functionality.

I now try to change the text of the label on both. However, the surrounding label is completely losing the `<input>` tag it is surrounding. It is just completely gone.

The other one works perfectly.

However, I would like to have it working the first way. Is there a possiblity to achieve this?

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The safe and best way is to replace your HTML to add a `<span>` for the text content and use `.text()` on the `<span>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $("#label1 span").text("test1234");
    $("#label2 span").text("test1234");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label id="label1">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <span>Label 1</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
    <label id = "label2" for="checkbox_id">
      <span>Label 2</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="clickMe">
  Click me
</button>
```

Comment: @Sossenbinder Welcome! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
    var childElement = $('#label1').find('input:checkbox');

    $("#label1").append(childElement).before(childElement).text('123');
    $("#label2").text("test1234");
  })
});
```

Or try it on your (updated) fiddle:

— <s>https://jsfiddle.net/9m4bgyq8/4/</s>

---

**EDIT**

This one is better:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
    var childElement = $('#label1').find('input:checkbox');

    $("#label1").html(childElement);
    $('#label1').append(' test1234');

    $("#label2").text("test1234");
  });
});
```

— https://jsfiddle.net/9m4bgyq8/12/

Comment: Oh.  That's much cleverer than I came up with.

Comment: This is also a very good answer, considering I don't even have to replace my label with a span

Answer (score 0):

You had the label tag outside of the input on the first one - once you switch that around it should work.

```
      <input type="checkbox"/>
  <label id="label1">
   Label 1
</label>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $("#label1").text("test1234");
    $("#label2").text("test1234");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <label id="label1">
       Label 1
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
    <label id = "label2" for="checkbox_id">
      Label 2
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="clickMe">
Click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try using native DOM manipulated like so :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $('#label1')[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue='123213';
  });
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/4tnhtxxq/)

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.text()` replaces the contents of a DOM node with the provided text. It's like emptying the element, then writing the text into it, so non-text child nodes are removed as well.

You could go over every `childNode`, check if it's a text node, and replace it with a new text - but there's a catch because there are probably more than one text nodes (white space also counts!). So I made a function that removes all text nodes and replaces the last one with new text:

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xhdr1z03/1/)

```
jQuery.fn.replaceText = function( newText ){
    this.each( function(element){
    [].slice.call(this.childNodes).forEach(function(node,i, nodes){
      if( node.nodeType == 3){
        if( i == nodes.length -1 ){  // last text node: change the text
            node.nodeValue = newText;
        }
        else { // any other text node: remove it
            node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs an answer that doesn't involve changing the markup, you can use:

```js
  $("#clickMe").click(function() {
    $("#label1").html($.trim($("#label1").html())).contents().filter(function(e) {
      if (this.nodeType === 3) this.nodeValue = ' test1234'
    });
    $("#label2").text("test1234");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label id="label1">
      <input type="checkbox" /> Label 1
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
    <label id="label2" for="checkbox_id">
      Label 2
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="clickMe">
  Click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure it does because jQuery .text() "set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text." (http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)

To solve your problem you can wrap the text you want to change in your label e.g.: `<span>Label 1</span>` https://jsfiddle.net/9m4bgyq8/2/